# Pls suggest me an example for dotchart's hover functionality using graphael

Tags: hover, raphael, graphael, bubble-chart

I am trying to create a dot chart(bubble chart) using gRaphael. But their documentation is not so clear on how to add hover effects when the user hovers on the dots.
Could any one pls suggest me some examples or give some help tips on the same.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply cancerbero.
Here is my java script solution,

```
dotChart.hover(function(){//onmouseover
        dotChart.covers = r.set();                                
        dotChart.covers.push(r.tag(this.x, this.y, this.value , 0, 10).insertBefore(this));                
    }, function(){//onmouseout
        if(dotChart.covers!=null){
            dotChart.covers.remove();
        }
    });
```

This has worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use aDotChart.hoverDot() for registering a "dot hover listener". The following is the source code of example http://cancerbero.vacau.com/gwt/graphael4gwtGallery/?test=dot1 that do what you mention. It is Java code not javascript! but i think it can help you to make an idea of the javascript code:

```
    double[] xs = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
            0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
            0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
            0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
            0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
            0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
            0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23};

    double[] ys = {7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
            6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
            5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
            4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
            3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};

    double[] data = {294, 300, 204, 255, 348, 383, 334, 217, 114, 33, 44, 26, 41, 39,
            52, 17, 13, 2, 0, 2, 5, 6, 64, 153, 294, 313, 195, 280, 365, 392, 340, 184,
            87, 35, 43, 55, 53, 79, 49, 19, 6, 1, 0, 1, 1, 10, 50, 181, 246, 246, 220,
            249, 355, 373, 332, 233, 85, 54, 28, 33, 45, 72, 54, 28, 5, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3,
            58, 167, 206, 245, 194, 207, 334, 290, 261, 160, 61, 28, 11, 26, 33, 46, 36,
            5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 9, 10, 7, 10, 14, 3, 3, 7, 0, 3, 4, 4, 6, 28, 24,
            3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 13, 10, 7, 2, 3, 6, 1, 9, 33, 32, 6,
            2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 4, 40, 128, 212, 263, 202, 248, 307, 306, 284, 222, 79, 39, 26,
            33, 40, 61, 54, 17, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 7, 70, 199};

    String[] axisy = {"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};
    String[] axisx = {"12am", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12pm", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"};

    DotOpts opts = new DotOpts();
    opts.setSymbol("o");
    opts.setMax(10);
    opts.setHeat(true);   
    opts.setAxis("0 0 1 1");
    opts.setAxisxlabels(axisx);
    opts.setAxisylabels(axisy);

    final DotChart c1 = getGPaper().dotchart(10, 10, 620, 260, xs, ys, data, opts);
    c1.hoverDot(new DotHoverListener() {

        @Override
        public void hoverOut(DotContext ctx) {
            if(tag!=null)
                tag.remove();
        }

        @Override
        public void hoverIn(DotContext ctx) {
                tag = (GShape) getGPaper().tag(ctx.getX(), ctx.getY(), ctx.getValue()+"", 0, ctx.getR()+2).
                        insertBefore(ctx).show();
        }
    });
```